# Why doesn't Visual Studio break on exceptions when debugging unit tests?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, debugging, exception

When I attempt to debug a unit test that fails because of an unhandled exception in my code, I expect Visual Studio to break on the unhandled exception so I can inspect the code and isolate the problem.  Instead, the IDE instantly exits debug mode and the test is listed as "Failed", leaving me to consult the test result's stack trace to find the problem.

I've confirmed that the IDE is configured to break when any user-unhandled CLR exception is thrown.  I can only get the expected behavior if I configure the IDE to break on all thrown exceptions.  This, of course, makes normal debugging a PITA.

Am I out of luck?

Comment: Could a high rep user replace the [visual-studio-2008] tag with [MSTest]? [This isn't specific to VS 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The reason why is that your exceptions are not unhandled.  The unit testing framework is handling the exceptions under the hood and converting them to failures.

What you need to do instead is to break on thrown exceptions.  If you combine this with enabling "Just My Code" (on by default) you should get the behavior you are expecting.  Visual Studio will only break when exceptions thrown by your code occur.

Comment: This is an acceptable workaround for now, but later on when my code matures and legit exceptions are thrown more often it will become a PITA.  Groan.

Comment: I get why, buyt I don't understand the workaround; in thicko terms, what do I click? For me, even "Debug Tests" doesn't hit breakpoints.

Comment: @Luke Puplett: Apparently, "Debug" menu -> "Exceptions..." -> Check "thrown" for the relevant exceptions.

Comment: See my answer below. If you at least know which exception is being thrown, you can break on that specific one.

Answer (score 8):

For me I am using VS 2010 and 2015, Go to:  Tools,  Options, Debugging, General: you need to make sure the "Enable Just My Code" and "Enable the exception assistant" should be checked.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that works for me in a similar scenario.

**If you notice that the debugger output is throwing handled exceptions you can note those exceptions.**

*Example*

[image]

**Take the ones you've just noted and open up the Exception Settings[image: Exception Settings]**

*Alternatively you can hit Ctrl+Alt+E*

**From there you'll see a number of specific exceptions you can enable your IDE to break on.**

*For example: ArgumentNullException*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The unit testing framework handles the exception so visual studio thinks that the exception is handled.

Answer (score 0):

By default, even if you do a debug build, MSTest does't give you debugging (with break points, etc), unless you actually tell it to explicitly "Debug Unit Tests".

It should break on unhandled exceptions in Unit testing, provided you are in a Debug configuration, **and** you start the Unit Testing using "Debug" - ie: Using `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+A` instead of `Ctrl+R, A` to run all tests.  In the testing window, there is a "Run" and a "Debug" menu with the options.

Comment: I was explicitly trying "Debug Unit Tests" using CTRL+R,CTRL+A or CTRL+R,CTRL+T.  Again, this approach only works if the debugger is configured to break on all *thrown* (rather than user-unhandled) exceptions, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:
Ctrl + Alt + E for Exceptions menu -> Press `Reset All`
Go to: Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General: you need to make sure both "Enable Just My Code" and "Enable the exception assistant" are checked.

Answer (score -1):

This is caused because by the fact that the tests are run using MSTest (with Visual Studio used simply as a shell). MSTest will mask these exceptions that are being thrown and they will never bubble up to Visual Studio. If you run the tests in debug mode it should work.

If you right click the test(s) in Test View and choose to debug them, it should run the code through the IDE and exceptions should break appropriately.

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work unless I configure the debugger to break on all *thrown* (rather than user-unhandled) exceptions, which is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Also the image link is now dead

Answer (score -2):

Install [Testdriven.NET](http://www.testdriven.net/), and use "Test With -> Debugger".