# Visual Studio does not break on unhandled exceptions when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Suddenly my `visual studio` does not break on unhandled exceptions and sometimes does not even stop on break points.

I have read many other related SO posts like these:

- [How to make visual studio break only on unhandled exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183099/how-to-make-visual-studio-break-only-on-unhandled-exceptions)
- [Why doesn't Visual Studio break on exceptions when debugging unit tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488282/why-doesnt-visual-studio-break-on-exceptions-when-debugging-unit-tests)

but none of the answers solved my problem.

When visual studio breaks on some of the exceptions it displays the following window:
[image]

but  I want the original 'way':
[image]

These are my `Debug\Exceptions` settings:
[image]

Can anyone please help me? This thing drive me crazy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is called the Exception Assistant.  The screenshot of the Exception dialog makes it clear you've been making changes in the dialog that also controls whether or not the Exception Assistant is enabled, you disabled Just My Code debugging.

Turn it back on.  Tools > Options > Debugging > General.  Tick the "Enable the exception assistant" option.