# visual studio error in browser not IDE debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Debugging a project on localhost, when there was an exception visual studio used to break in the IDE and I could inspect variables etc.  If I pressed F5 the same error would display in the browser.

I've done something in the settings and now the browser just displays the error and debugging stops.  The browser looks like this:

[image]

How do I go back to where it would stop in the IDE and show something like this (I've screen grabbed a breakpoint, but it would have been an exception before)

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307330/debugger-does-not-stop-on-error

Comment: @AlexK.   Ya man - thanks. That was it.  Same as that Q - Just my code got it to break in the IDE.

Comment: I've come back to this as it was a royal pain, and a few days later I'm here again.  I rechecked the "just my code" setting and it was set.  But still no exception assistant.  I looked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020374/a-first-chance-exception and tryed Debugger.. Exceptions, Checking CLR.   Bingo it reappeared.